# Convert this in to the standard form of an ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry

$$ \frac{p^2+q^2a^2}{a^2}-\frac{\left(2px+2qa^2y-a^2\right)}{a^2y^2+x^2}=k^2$$

How to put the above equation into this form?
$$\frac{\left(X-H\right)^2}{A^2}+\frac{\left(Y-K\right)^2}{B^2}=1$$

The algebra is killing me :) Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried my hardest and well I'm stuck with this... 
$$p^2x^2+q^2a^2x^2-k^2a^2x^2+p^2a^2y^2+q^2a^4y^2-k^2a^4y^2-2pa^2x-2qa^4x+a^4=0$$ really don't know what to do from here on.

Comment: I tried to do completing the square method... but I just don't know which squares to "complete" because there are so many variables... If someone could just tell me which squares to complete I will be A-Okay.... :>

Comment: Note that you can cancel $a^2y^2+x^2$ in the first term

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks! I will edit the question with that

Comment: @MarkBennet I've expanded everything out and well I'm just stuck with this equation (which really doesn't say anything to me at all) $$p^2x^2+q^2a^2x^2-k^2a^2x^2+p^2a^2y^2+q^2a^4y^2-k^2a^4y^2-2pa^2x-2qa^4x+a^4=0$$ I'm going to include this in the question as well

Comment: So $(p^2+q^2a^2-k^2a^2)x^2+a^2(p^2+q^2a^2-k^2a^2)y^2+ \dots$. Now if the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive call it $C^2$ (otherwise $-C^2$) to obtain $C^2x^2+a^2C^2y^2+\dots $. Then complete the square using $D, E$ instead of any complicated expressions which occur. You can substitute back at the end.

Comment: @MarkBennet sorry to bother you again! This is the last time. If $p^2+q^2a^2-k^2a^2$ is $C$ then why $C^2$?
Also what i eventually get is this...
$$Cx^2-2a^2px+a^4+Ca^2y^2-2ya^4q=0\\$$
Could you just help convert this into the standard form
$$\frac{\left(X-H\right)^2}{A^2}+\frac{\left(Y-K\right)^2}{B^2}=1$$
And then I'll be done. :)

Comment: See [the previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450131/convert-this-equation-into-the-standard-form-of-an-ellipse) for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p^2+q^2a^2-k^2a^2=C$ (I used $C^2$ in the comments for 'dimensional' reasons))

to obtain $$Cx^2-2a^2px+a^2(Cy^2-2a^2qy)+a^4=0$$

You can then multiply through by $C$ and complete the square to obtain $$(Cx-a^2p)^2+a^2(Cy-a^2q)^2=a^4(p^2+a^2q^2-C)=k^2a^6$$

And you should be able to complete it from there.

Comment: Just curious - what are the dimensional reasons? I'm a mere high schooler I wouldn't know... If there is a link to help that would be great too :) Thanks!

Comment: @soupynoodles What I mean roughly is that it looks like it might be the square of something. If you have $C^2x-a^2p$ for example, the total degree of each term is $3$

Comment: what is done above makes complete sense, save for the last bit. What does the term $k^2a^6$ mean? It is non-existent in my algebra on paper...

Comment: @soupynoodles It comes from the squared terms which you have to put in on the left-hand side to complete the square. Note that $p^2+a^2q^2-C=k^2a^2$

Comment: Thanks :) I don't really get the square (dimensional) bit though... if you have the time could you clarify that a bit? --reallycurious

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Regroup the terms with equal powers of $x$ and $y$ (actually, you just have term in $x^2,x,y^2,1$ which isn't that much).

The standard form of the ellipse equation is the sum of two squares, the one generating terms in $x^2,x,1$, and the other $y^2,y,1$.

So it seems that you can just handle $x$ and $y$ separately for square completion.

$$a(x+b)^2+c(y+d)^2+e=ax^2+(2ab)x+cy^2+(2cd)y+(b^2+d^2+e).$$

Note that the lack of an $y$ term is not an obstacle to square completion, on the opposite.