# Curvature of Ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

We all know that the curvature of a circle is defined by the equation
$$k=\frac{1}{r}$$

What about ellipses?

In terms of major axis $a$, minor axis $b$, $x$ and $y$, what is the curvature of an ellipse?

Thanks lots!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x=a\cos(t),y=b\sin(t)$$
$$\dot x=-a\sin(t),\dot y=b\cos(t)$$
$$\ddot x=-a\cos(t),\ddot y=-b\sin(t)$$

$$\kappa=\frac{\dot x\ddot y-\ddot x\dot y}{(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{ab}{(a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t))^{3/2}}=\frac{ab}{((\frac ab y)^2+(\frac bax)^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust. So if I were to plub in x and y coordinates along with the major and minor axes, I get the curvature of the ellipse at that coordinate, yes?

Comment: Hem, what else ?

Comment: Righto... Please don't get too mad at a mere high schooler. Just one last question - where do you get that formula for k?  
Actually one more thing - can you show to generalize this for a circle?

Comment: Have you heard of Google ?

Comment: @soupynoodles just put $a=b$ and $ x^2+y^2 =a^2$ in Yves Daoust's formula.

Comment: Just as a derivative gives you the “instantaneous slope” of a curve by finding the line that best approximates the curve at a point, the above gives you “instantaneous curvature” by finding the circle that best approximates the curve at a given point.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the curvature in parametric form [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipseEvolute.html), tag 11.

Answer (score -1):

The second answer is the maximum principal curvature, as explained on pages 71-76 of "Vector and Tensor Analysis" by Harry Lass, McGraw-Hill (1950).  The denominator is G^{3/2}, where G is the third term in the first fundamental form for the Ellipse.  The minimal principal curvature is c / ( a \sqrt{G}).